# Is ecx register used to pass one of the parameters in a static function call?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I know that when calling a non-static member function of an object in c++, the this pointer is passed in ecx register. What about static functions, as there is no this pointer, does the compiler use ecx register to pass one of the regular parameters in this case?

Edit - I'm talking about the cdecl calling convention here.

Comment: [Looks like it depends on the calling convention.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions) Some conventions do, some don't.

Comment: I suspect since there is no need to lookup the address for the specific object, it simply does call to that address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `ecx` (or any other register) is used for when calling functions depends on the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

For instance, consider the C++ code

```
struct S {
    static void f( int, int ) { }
    void g( int ) { }
};

void g() {
    S::f( 3, 4 );
    S s;
    s.g( 3 );
}
```

Compiling this with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (64bit) via

```
cl /c main.cpp
```

And then dumping the assembly via

```
dumpbin /disasm main.obj
```

Gives this for the `g` function:

```
?g@@YAXXZ (void __cdecl g(void)):
  0000000000000000: 48 83 EC 38        sub         rsp,38h
  0000000000000004: BA 04 00 00 00     mov         edx,4
  0000000000000009: B9 03 00 00 00     mov         ecx,3
  000000000000000E: E8 00 00 00 00     call        ?f@S@@SAXHH@Z
  0000000000000013: BA 03 00 00 00     mov         edx,3
  0000000000000018: 48 8D 4C 24 20     lea         rcx,[rsp+20h]
  000000000000001D: E8 00 00 00 00     call        ?g@S@@QEAAXH@Z
  0000000000000022: 48 83 C4 38        add         rsp,38h
  0000000000000026: C3                 ret
```

Notice how the first call to the static `S::f` method has the first argment (3) passed in `ecx` and the second argment (4) in `edx`. So the answer to your question is:

Yes. For this particular compiler, `ecx` is used to pass one of the parameters in a static function call.

Comment: Answering my own question - apparently the 32 bit visual studio compiler does the same as you described. Thanks.